# adding audio to appsrc video pipeline

Tags: gstreamer, http-live-streaming

I'm using appsrc to generate an HLS stream, this is my successful pipeline:

appsrc->videoconvert->openh264enc->h264parse->mpegtsmux->hlssink

However, I'd like to generate some audio via audiotestsrc before mpegtsmux which would look like the following:

audiotestsrc->lamemp3enc->mpegtsmux

Audiotestsrc and lame have 'always' pads, so I link the two just like my other video elements.

When it comes to linking lame's "always" "src", to mpegtsmux's "request" "sink_%d", the result says that there's no issue:

```
//Returns 0
gst_pad_link(h264ParsePad, mpegtsmuxSinkPad);

//Returns 0
gst_pad_link(audioEncPad, mpegtsmuxSinkPad);

//Returns 0
gst_pad_link(mpegtsmuxSrcPad, hlssinkPad);
```

But running the app results in pipeline failure with

```
"Internal data stream error."
```

Removing the audioEncPad linking just makes the stream work like normal but of course without audio. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things needed to be done:

1. Use aacparse
2. Clean the solution
3. Link voaacenc with aacparse

#2 caused me a lot of torment since everything theoretically should've worked. D'oh.